# Separating Chat Messages

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm using `JSMessagesViewController` and currently I'm using one `NSMutableArray`. (long story short, it's just a chat UI). The chat is only between 2 people and I was wondering, if all the messages go into 1(one) `NSMutableArray`, how do I differentiate the messages between the 2 users?

Right now I can create a straight list, but I need a way to differentiate it since they are on opposite sides of the table.

Comment: Can you share your JSMessagesViewController.?

Comment: So where is what You have tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Look at the code?! `JSBubbleMessageTypeOutgoing` sounds like it could be related to differentiate between incoming and outgoing messages.

Comment: @VineeshTP https://github.com/jessesquires/MessagesTableViewController

Comment: @MatthiasBauch yes, but for example; when I add a message and set it to Outgoing, it changes them all to Outgoing.

Comment: I can differentiate them by indexPath.row ..... but how will the code know who sent what? I can do indexPath.row % 2 and it'd swap off each row for outgoing and incoming. I need a way to set it know which indexpath will be an outgoing message... Maybe i'm overthinking this?

Comment: @Bomiz could you show us the code, where you add a message into `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: [self.messages addObject:[[JSMessage alloc] initWithText:text sender:sender date:date]];  but then JSMessage encrypts it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a second `NSMutableArray` that holds at the same index the author of the message. An alternative solution would be to use the one `NSMutableArray` and mix up author and message, so you have first element author, second message, third next author, fourth the message, ....

Last but not least another solution would be to use one `NSMutableArray` and add `NSDictionary`as object. The dictionary can have two keys, author and message four example. This last approach would allow you to expand the dictionary to contain for example a timestamp for each message or tags or whatever you think of later.

Answer (score 0):

You have method

```
                 [self.messages addObject:[[JSMessage alloc] initWithText:message.body sender:kSourceUserName date:message.timestamp]];
```

You can set 'sender:' as user id and then retranslate it to user name

Or on start up your VC you can load 2 users with they id and then assign messages to them as source(self user) and destination user

Answer (score 0):

In my case , i have message array with isOutgoing key, when i m creating jsqmessage m checking that key , if it isOutgoing then add senderId , and if !isOutgoing then add reciver name senderId, then loading message , it will be in opposite side.